# Error converting nvarchar to int in count in having clause

Tags: sql

```
SELECT     
    dbo.RtlStore.Description, 
    COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS CONSIGNMENT, 
    COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS OUTRIGHT, 
    COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS HOURSEBRAND, 
    COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS GOI, 
    COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS OTHERS
FROM
    dbo.RtlStore 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.InvProduct 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem ON dbo.InvProduct.ProductKey = dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.ProductKey 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TrxTransaction ON dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.TransactionKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.TransactionKey 
    ON dbo.RtlStore.StoreKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.StoreKey
GROUP BY 
    dbo.RtlStore.Description
HAVING     
    (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'CONSIGNMENT')
    AND (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'OUTRIGHT')  
    AND (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'HOUSEBRAND') 
    AND (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'GOI')
    AND (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'OTHERS')
```

Comment: What you are doing is comparing COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) which is numeric to 'CONSIGNMENT' which is a string, can only compare similar data types..

Comment: Tell us what are you trying to do here

Comment: IT IS FROM A COMBOBOX, I NEED TO EXTRACT IT INTO COLUMNS FOR THE REPORT. PLS HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to pivot the data?  If so try this:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.RtlStore.Description, 
    max(case when dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'CONSIGNMENT' then 1 else null end) AS CONSIGNMENT, 
    max(case when dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'OUTRIGHT' then 1 else null end) AS OUTRIGHT, 
    max(case when dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'HOUSEBRAND' then 1 else null end) AS HOURSEBRAND, 
    max(case when dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'GOI' then 1 else null end) AS GOI, 
    max(case when dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'OTHERS' then 1 else null end) AS OTHERS
FROM
    dbo.RtlStore 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.InvProduct 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem ON dbo.InvProduct.ProductKey = dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.ProductKey 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TrxTransaction ON dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.TransactionKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.TransactionKey 
    ON dbo.RtlStore.StoreKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.StoreKey
GROUP BY 
    dbo.RtlStore.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

try to comment the HAVING part at the moment and see if that is going to help, once you get the results you can then filter it using HAVING

```
SELECT     dbo.RtlStore.Description, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS CONSIGNMENT, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS OUTRIGHT, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) 
                      AS HOURSEBRAND, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS GOI, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS OTHERS
FROM         dbo.RtlStore LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.InvProduct LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem ON dbo.InvProduct.ProductKey = dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.ProductKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.TrxTransaction ON dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.TransactionKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.TransactionKey ON dbo.RtlStore.StoreKey = dbo.TrxTransaction.StoreKey
GROUP BY dbo.RtlStore.Description
--HAVING     


--             (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'CONSIGNMENT')
--       AND   (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'OUTRIGHT')  
--       AND   (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'HOUSEBRAND') 
--       AND   (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'GOI')
--       AND   (COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) = N'OTHERS')
```